# Magnetic field of circular wire geometry question

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, geometry

Hi does anyone know how to prove that the $\theta$ between the vectors $\vec{B}$ and $d \vec{B}$ are equivalent to the $\theta$ between $R$ and 'curl r' (I don't think the latex font is available for that symbol)? A hint would suffice, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please edit your question, describing the problem and what point of the solution you are stuck with - a picture of the solution is a) hard to read and b) it leaves us guessing at the actual question.

Comment: @Sanya I just want to know the geometry question as stated above. I understand the rest of the proof. The picture becomes clearer when you click on it. I edited the picture to include the question (it was omitted by mistake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram is a little misleading because of the perspective.

[image]

Triangles $XYZ, ZOW$ and $ZYW$ are all in the same plane.
That plane contains the vectors $\vec R, \vec r$ and $d \vec B$.

$d \vec B$ is along a tangent to a circle of radius $|\vec r|$ whose plane is in the plane of the three triangles.
This circle represents the field line in the plane of the three triangle which is produced by the current element.

The current element $d \vec I$ is along line $JK$ and is at right angles to the plane that contains the three triangles.
So your statement that the angle between $\vec R$ and $d \vec I$ is $\theta$ is not correct as that angle is $90^\circ$.

Hopefully this makes it clear that angle $ZWO$ is equal to angle $XZY$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My statement you are referring to, was a typo not an error in understanding, I have corrected this. By $\vec{r}$ are you referring to the curly vector from W to Z, if so how do you get that the circle that $d \vec{B}$ points to is a circle of radius $|\vec{r}|$? How are the two $\theta$s equal from these observations?

Comment: The top circle is the locus of the tips of $d\ vec B$ produced by different current elements $d\vec I$.  So you can think of all the $d\ vec B$ vectors forming a cone and you have to find the sum of all those vectors.  The text tells you that the horizontal components perpendicular to $\hat z$ cancel out so you the only have a $B_{\rm z}$.

Comment: Look at the angle sum of the triangle $ZOW$ and the angle sum along the straight line $OZX$.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying! So for angle $\angle OZW = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$. Since $\angle OZX = \pi$, we have that $\angle XZY = \pi - (\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta) - \frac{\pi}{2} = \theta$.

Comment: I sometimes use wooden spills (used for lighting candles) and/or pipe cleaners with blutac to construct 3D models to sort out the geometry.